# How can I dismiss a custom delete function of a std smart pointer?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I have introduced a FreeGuard class that cleans up a resource if initialization fails:

```
struct Resource {...};

class FreeGuard {
public:
    FreeGuard(Resource* r) : resource(r) {};
    ~FreeGuard() {
        if (!dismissed) {
            freeResource(resource);
        }
    }
    void dismiss() { dismissed = true; }

private:
    bool dismissed = false;
    Resource* resource;
};

int init(Resource* r) {
    FreeGuard guard(r);
    if (...)
        return -1;
    if (...)
        return -2;
    ...
    if (...)
        return -1000;
    guard.dismiss();
    return 0;
}

int freeResource(Resource* r) {...}
```

How can I achieve the same with std smart pointers so that I do not have to keep writing FreeGuard classes?

Comment: Why do you have a wrapper function at all? A [RIAA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) design shouldn't need this. The design here looks like it either releases something, or maybe doesn't, and leaks memory?

Comment: I don't get the point of your `FreeGuard`. You want to free the resource, but only sometimes and sometimes not? The idiomatic approach is to use RAII.

Comment: This looks like some kind of really wonky reference-counting pointer, but it can only count up to 1. A [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) would be way better. It's also unusual to see `free` inside of C++ code. Is this wrapping some kind of C library or structure?

Comment: it's not clear if the function `init` has the ownership of `Resource* r`, if so (and maybe you will transmit `r` to any other function after `dismiss`), use `std::unique_ptr<Resource, some_deleter_by_free>`. and it's also confused if the caller of `init` still has the ownership, if so, use `std::shared_ptr<Resource>` and `std::weak_ptr<Resource>`.

Comment: actually, it could be different in each case dependent on what you do before and after `dismiss` and how the ownership transmits. but if you don't care, just replace `Resource*` by `std::shared_ptr<Resource>`, except circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `release()` function of `unique_ptr`. This is a common pattern for exception-safe code when dealing with non-RAII resources (like C library handles):

```
#include <memory>

int freeResource(Resource* r) {...}

int init(Resource* r) {
    std::unique_ptr<Resource, decltype(&freeResource)> guard(r, freeResource);
    if (...)
        return -1;
    if (...)
        return -2;
    ...
    if (...)
        return -1000;
    guard.release(); // releases ownership, deleter will not be called
    return 0;
}
```

Just rename your `free()` function to something else (here, `freeResource()`) to avoid conflict with the standard `free()` function.

Comment: A note on usage: you would *usually* capture the return value of `release()` because otherwise the resource is lost (unless you previously called `get()` or otherwise got a handle of the resource). In fact, I’d call it a minor code smell to not capture `release()`’s return value, and the function should probably be annotated `[[nodiscard]]` in a future standard version.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True, but in this case I think it's clear that `init()` is a function that tries to initialize the resource and, if that fails, frees it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph One other thing: calling `release()` in general and capturing its return value in a raw pointer is also a code smell IMO, because you'd have an unmanaged pointer. From that point of view, the only "valid" thing to do with `release()` is to use it as an argument to the ctor or to `reset()` of another `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Nikos C: thank you! A lot easier than writing Guard classes.

Comment: @NikosC. The only valid use-case for that which I can think of is to pass the resource to an unmanaged API. And the only use-case I can think of for calling `release()` without capturing the value is when intentionally leaking a resource, which should be done extremely rarely (for performance reasons when leaking is safe). OP’s use-case doesn’t seem legitimate, to be honest: `freeResource` *should* be callable. For example, `free` on a null pointer is a no-op, no need to call `release`.

Comment: (To clarify, my comments aren’t meant to criticise the answer, which is 100% correct; I’m just adding some more context.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph One thing to keep in mind here is that this use of `unique_ptr` is a replacement for scope guards (like you have in D, for example.) There, you'd use `scope(exit) free(r)` instead, and the `release()` would be replaced with `r = null`. Since we don't have that in C++ (as a language or standard library facility), we have to use `unique_ptr` instead. Some people consider this an abuse of `unique_ptr`. But hey, sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do :-) I say it's a somewhat readable way to express local transactional semantics (where `release()` or `r = null` is the commit.)